# How to loop a sound after I use a soundchannel.stop() in the same sound? AS3 - FlashDevelop

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, audio

I'm having a hard time to solve a sound loop in a screen that i have created, i would love if you could help me. I have created two screens: a startScreen and a gameScreen.If is the startScreen it plays a "bg sound", if is in the gameScreen the "bg sound" from the startScreen stop(i used the soundchannel.stop()). So far is okay but the soundchannel.stop(); doesn't make the sound be able to play again everytime is in the startScreen. Is there a possible to stop a sound without the soundchannel.stop(); and start again the sound from the begning everytime is in startScreen? heres a part of the code i have ben using:

```
private var scSound:Sound = new SCSOUND();
private var scSoundChannel:SoundChannel = scSound.play(0, 999);

private function initStartScreen():void
    {
        startScreen.visible = true;
        gameScreen.visible = false;

        scSoundChannel;
    }
    private function initGameScreen():void
    {
        gameScreen.visible = true;
        startScreen.visible = false;

        scSoundChannel.stop();

    }
```

I tried to add a addEventListener for the sound but the removeEventListener doesn't wanna remove the sound.

Comment: Hi i just solved, i just did add scSoundChannel = scSound.play(0, 999); again but in initGameScreen and it worked! Thanks for those who view this post.